# Compare to column in excel and return a value from corresponding third column to a new column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

for example i have 3 column:

[image]

I whant the result in a new column as:

[image]

by comparing C with A return B

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a VLOOKUP command or a MATCH INDEX one like below:

[image]

Notice how I handle the error of not finding anything too.

Simply drag this formula down to fill out everything.

Comment: Insted of "NO" whether we can retain the previous result in the cell??

Comment: Yea replace with a referencing cell to the one above it.